# Laravel: multiple auth method implementation

Tags: php, authentication, laravel

In one laravel project, I would have two auth method:

1. API client authentication (to check if client can query the API) with dedicated eloquent model (something like APIUser)
2. User authentication (to check user credential) with another dedicated model (Something User)

I would like to authenticate through first auth system then check a user credential through second auth system. Example :

`curl -u a:b myapi/?user=c&pass=d`

So `a`&`b` are login and password for API client authentication and `c`&`d` are login and password for user authentication. What can be the best way to do that: create a multi-auth system ? or consider only one system is for auth, the other is just querying database ? or something else ? (hope my question is clear enough, I can edit if you need)

Answer (score 0):

[Multiauth](https://github.com/ollieread/multiauth) works like a build-in laravel auth, but allow few independent auth sessions (you can login on first, second or both accounts).

Comment: Thanks ! As I said to Kousha, my question was not about "is there a multiauth system in laravel" but "should I use a multiauth system for that". Sorry, my question was not so clear... I will edit soon. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Yes, i suppose you should implement multiauth for security reasons. You never know how user use these api credentials (he could send it as a plain text)

Answer (score 0):

Use Ollieread's [MultiAuth](https://github.com/ollieread/multiauth) extension for Laravel. It sets everything up for you. Just open up the file `app/config/auth.php` and replace this array:

```
return array(
    'driver' => 'eloquent',
    'model' => 'User',
    'table' => 'users',
    'reminder' => array(
        'email' => 'emails.auth.reminder',
        'table' => 'password_reminders',
        'expire' => 60,
    ),
);
```

with

```
return array(
    'multi' => array(
        'admin' => array(
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => 'Admin'
        ),
        'user' => array(
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table' => 'users'
        )
    ),

    'reminder' => array(
        'email' => 'emails.auth.reminder',
        'table' => 'password_reminders',
        'expire' => 60,
    ),
);
```

Of course, you can add as many as you want. Then copy paste the default `User.php` model for your `Admin.php` table.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for your answer ! My question was not about how to use Ollieread's MultiAuth  with user and admin but: what is the best way to (1) connect to an api through http basic (2) then check user credential ? create (or use) a multiauth system (like Ollieread's MultiAuth) ? or consider only one system is for auth (http basic for API auth), the other is just querying database (check credential in database then return true or false to api client)? or something else ? It's not about user level (There is no "user" and "admin" context). Hope it's clear enough (sorry it wasn't). Thanks :)

Comment: @rap-2-h, is your 'client' more like a permission? Or is it a whole another user-system? If you actually have two types of users (User and Client), then you should use a multi-auth system for security reasons. If you only have one type of users, who may have different permissions (like moderators, reviewers), then you can implement an ACL.

Comment: The word "client" is for "client/server", not a user type. Sorry for the misunderstanding